# Uncaught Reference Error: variable undefined

Tags: javascript, html, oop, referenceerror

I'm trying to define a class in a separate javascript file and then use that class in my HTML file.

Here's what I'm trying.

1. I create the class VoiceCard in the VoiceCard.js file:

```
class VoiceCard {
    constructor(nickname, date_time, post_title, voice_post) {
        this.nickname = nickname;
        this.date_time = date_time;
        this.post_title = post_title;
        this.voice_post = voice_post;
    }
```

2. I create an HTML file where I add the file as the source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="module" src="../VoiceCard.js"></script>
</head>
```

3. I create a script where I call the class to create a new variable of the VoiceCard class and log one of the attributes to the console:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="module" src="../VoiceCard.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    let v_card = new VoiceCard(
        "Lorder",
        "12:00",
        "First Voicer Post",
        "file_location.mp4");

    console.log(v_card.nickname);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The error is: Uncaught ReferenceError: VoiceCard is not defined.

I can't seem to find the reason for the error. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modules don't create globals. That's most of the point of them. :-)

Here's how to do what you seem to want to do:

1. Remove the `script` tag for `VoiceCard.js`.
2. In `VoiceCard.js`, **export** the class by adding `export` in front of `class`.
3. Change your inline script to an inline module that imports the class from the `VoiceCard.js` file.

So:

```js
export class VoiceCard {
// ^^^
    constructor(nickname, date_time, post_title, voice_post) {
        this.nickname = nickname;
        this.date_time = date_time;
        this.post_title = post_title;
        this.voice_post = voice_post;
    }
} // <== This closing `}` was missing
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- No script tag for VoiceCard -->
</head>
<body>
<script type="module">
import { VoiceCard } from "../VoiceCard.js"; // ***
let v_card = new VoiceCard(
    "Lorder",
    "12:00",
    "First Voicer Post",
    "file_location.mp4"
);
console.log(v_card.nickname);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The browser will download `VoiceCard.js` automatically when it sees the `import`.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you it solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

You can remove `type="module"` to fix this problem

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="../VoiceCard.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    let v_card = new VoiceCard(
        "Lorder",
        "12:00",
        "First Voicer Post",
        "file_location.mp4");

    console.log(v_card.nickname);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: LOL true, if you want to just use globals, you can do it that way. :-)